# How do I use a cd reader from old laptop (taken out) without buying an enclosure?

Tags: external-hard-drive, sata

I took disc drive out of old laptop and it has the sata port in laptop, can I just convert the sata cord into a sata to usb cord and hook it up as an external drive? I live in BFE so I dont want to wait 7 days for an enclosure to be sent to me. If an enclosure is essential to get disc drive power, how can I bypass the enclosure? Does this make sense what Im asking?

Comment: That does not seem likely to me. Does the old computer run?  Get the data on the old computer and transfer it to the new one. Otherwise you need the correct part.

Comment: It's either an enclosure or a "bare" cable with equivalent SATA-USB converter. Both likely to come from the exact same place and take the same time to your destination. And, WOW, just WOW... *I dont want to wait 7 days* is such a first world problem. Best deals are still directly from China (e.g. Aliexpress) and may take longer, 2, 3, 4 or more weeks.

Comment: If it is using a standard SATA connector then probably yes. But this depends on whether the connector is standard or proprietary, and whether there's an enclosure that fits the drive.

Answer (score 0):

If the drive is using a standard connector, you will be able to find an adapter that works.

If an enclosure exists that the drive will fit in that has the appropriate connectors, you'll be able to use this.

If the enclosure doesn't exist that your drive fits in, you won't be able to do this.

If your drive uses a proprietary connector, unless an adapter is made for that, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need either an enclosure or a *slimline SATA* adapter. SATA by itself is not a problem, but you have to provide the power too using the other half of the connector, and it's smaller than a regular SATA power connector.